# How to do partial fraction decomposition.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I have a to solve.$$\int\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)^2(b-x)}dx$$
But I don't even know how to start it. Please help.

Comment: $$\dfrac{2}{(a-2 b)^2 (2 x-a)}-\dfrac{2}{(a-2 b) (2 x-a)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(a-2 b)^2 (x-b)}$$

Comment: Do you know how to do problems like this if instead of $a$ and $b$, you had numbers?

Comment: **Hint:** Find $A,B,C\in\Re$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{(a-2x)^2(b-x)}=\frac{Ax+B}{(a-2x)^2}+\frac{C}{b-x}.$$
Then you should be able to work out the rest.

Comment: @user65018, I don't believe your solution is correct. I think that the OP should find $A, B, C \in \Bbb R$ such that
$$\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)^2(b-x)} = \dfrac{A}{(a-2x)^2} +  \dfrac{B}{(a-2x)} +  \dfrac{C}{b-x}$$
since (a-2x)^2 is not an irreducible quadratic. From my understanding, you would only use $Ax+B$ in the numerator if the denominator could never equal zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with
$$
\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)(b-x)}=\dfrac{1}{a-2b}\left(\dfrac{-2}{a-2x}+\dfrac{1}{b-x}\right),
$$
we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)^2(b-x)}&=&\dfrac{1}{a-2b}\left[\dfrac{-2}{(a-2x)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)(b-x)}\right]\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{a-2b}\left[\dfrac{-2}{(a-2x)^2}+\dfrac{1}{a-2b}\left(\dfrac{-2}{a-2x}+\dfrac{1}{b-x}\right)\right]\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{2b-a}\cdot\dfrac{2}{(2x-a)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{2x-a}-\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-b}.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\dfrac{1}{(a-2x)^2(b-x)}\,dx&=&\int\left[\dfrac{1}{2b-a}\cdot\dfrac{2}{(2x-a)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{2x-a}-\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-b}\right]\,dx\\
&=&\dfrac{-1}{2b-a}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2x-a}+\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\ln|2x-a|-\dfrac{1}{(2b-a)^2}\cdot\ln|x-b|+c
\end{eqnarray}